# Detect XHR error is really due to browser stop or click to new page

Tags: javascript, browser, xmlhttprequest

While my page is loading content via XHR, if the user clicks the stop button or clicks to go to another page, the XHR error() function is called. This wouldn't normally be a big deal except for the user shock of seeing lots of (red) error messages on the page.

The messages are valid - there was indeed an error retrieving the content - but it's due to the user interaction, not because of a system failure.

Is there a way to distinguish between a (404 | 500 | timeout error) and an error caused by the fact that the user hit the browser's stop button ?

EDIT: I am using Dojo (hence the error function reference), but I believe this would be a situation that is common across any XHR implementation. I will look into readyState of the xhr object when error() is called

Comment: What "XHR error() function" are you referring to? There is no such method on `XmlHttpRequest` instances.

Comment: appears there is an "onerror" event supported by "most" browsers, apparently. ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget/onerror

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To distinguish between HTTP errors (`404`, `401`, `403`, `500`, etc..) and request abortion errors (i.e. the user pressed Esc or navigated to other page) , you can check the XHR.status property, if the request has been aborted the status member will be zero:

```
document.getElementById('element').onclick = function () { 
  postRequest ('test/', null, function (response) { // success callback
    alert('Response: ' + response); 
  }, function (xhr, status) { // error callback
    switch(status) { 
      case 404: 
        alert('File not found'); 
        break; 
      case 500: 
        alert('Server error'); 
        break; 
      case 0: 
        alert('Request aborted'); 
        break; 
      default: 
        alert('Unknown error ' + status); 
    } 
  }); 
};
```

A simple postRequest function:

```
function postRequest (url, params, success, error) {  
  var xhr = XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : 
                             new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
  xhr.open("POST", url, true); 
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){ 
    if ( xhr.readyState == 4 ) { 
      if ( xhr.status == 200 ) { 
    success(xhr.responseText); 
      } else { 
    error(xhr, xhr.status); 
      } 
    } 
  }; 
  xhr.onerror = function () { 
    error(xhr, xhr.status); 
  }; 
  xhr.send(params); 
}
```

Run the above snippet [here](http://jsbin.com/usufa).

Comment: Perfect - a status of 0 was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: A connection failure will also have a status of 0. Not sure how to tell the difference between a manually cancelled connection and a connection failure

Comment: What Jaffa said. A request denied by CORS policy also has a status of 0. I'm very curious as to whether there is a way to tell, across browsers, if an XHR has status 0 specifically because it was aborted by the browser.

Comment: agree with @JaffaTheCake this does not work in that scenario. I have however used this solution to get around that:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326627/jquery-ajax-error-when-leaving-page

Comment: Unfortunately the second snippet there seems to call the "error" handler twice whenever there is a failure :|

Comment: There are several cases for a 0 status. I am also looking for a solution which can distinguish these cases.

Comment: How to get request data in the response?